# How to clear the cache in the browser after cache?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I accidentally set a cache for my index file in my application. now I remove this cache policy.

The problem is anyone access to my website got the cached `index.html`.

How can I refresh the cache? I can't tell all my users across the world to clean the cache..

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: TL;DR: you can't. Wait for the existing caches to expire, and if that won't work because you've set it to cache for a year or something, you need to change the URL (i.e. cache busting).

Comment: usually in the way you set the cache policy there is a cache invalidate instruction. If not an wasy way is to change the filename (*ie* make the index route go to index1.html)

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's javascript files which are cached. A pragmatic approach would be to add an argument to you script imports e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js?buildNo=123"></script>
```